# L'astronaute du Canada/Québec : préfixation nationale, néologisme, pour diffusion grand public ?

Tags: régionalismes, néologismes, préfixes, science, suffixes

Je [lis](https://www.lapresse.ca/sciences/astronomie-et-espace/201901/06/01-5210081-la-chine-rivale-celeste-des-etats-unis.php) que la Chine veut qu'un « taïkonaute » (néologisme [du chinois 太空人 (tàikōngrén)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronaute#Ta%C3%AFkonaute) ; [Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ta%C3%AFkonaute/10910021?q=ta%C3%AFkonaute#802509), [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ta%C3%AFkonaute), [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26502470), en note sur [FranceTerme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=astronaute&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search)), un astronaute, soit de nationalité chinoise, soit dans une fusée chinoise, soit dans le cadre du programme spatial chinois, marche sur la Lune dans les années 2030. La concurrence des termes (**dans les médias** et non pas chez les professionnels de l'astronautique, en terminologie) découle d'une effet d'entraînement relié à la guerre froide (Wikipédia). Ceci appelle une réflexion :

> Comment appellera-t-on en français un astronaute suédois ? Ou un
>   cosmonaute rwandais ? Nul ne sait. [...] Certains ont propagé l'idée
>   qu'il faudrait employer des termes différents selon la nationalité de
>   l'homme de l'espace : astronaute pour un citoyen des États-Unis,
>   cosmonaute pour un Russe, spationaute pour un Européen et taïkonaute
>   pour un Chinois. Ce serait le seul exemple dans toute la langue
>   française d'un nom de métier adapté à la nationalité du professionnel
>   ! Un danseur, un cuisinier ou un architecte ne changent pas de nom
>   selon leur pays d'origine. Pas davantage dans le sport - haut lieu du
>   chauvinisme, pourtant. En français journalistique, un patineur et un
>   nageur restent un patineur et un nageur quelle que soit leur
>   nationalité.
>
> [...] Les professionnels francophones de l'information et leur public
>   sont donc invités à renoncer à cette idée reçue absurde selon laquelle
>   il faudrait employer des mots différents pour qualifier les
>   cosmonautes ou astronautes des différents pays du monde. Cette lubie
>   est d'autant plus sidérante que la navigation spatiale ne connaît ni
>   frontières ni contours territoriaux d'aucune sorte.
>
> [ Frédéric Allinne, *Convergence numérique et communication
>   linguistique*, éd. CELSA, 2008, p. 82 sur [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronaute#Terminologie) ]

Non, plus dans le contexte actuel où à mon avis le [marché des idées](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=MARKETPLACE%20IDEAS&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) ([*marketplace of ideas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marketplace_of_ideas)) est désintégré, quoique l'argument de cohérence reste valable et intéressant. Par ailleurs, être astronaute n'est pas un métier<sup>1</sup>. Voler dans l'espace est un *privilège rare* et seulement 500 personnes ont eu droit à cet honneur en plus de 50 ans d'histoire en astronautique (Wikipédia). Quel métier sur la planète est-il réservé à uniquement 500 personnes ? Le Canada est un pionnier<sup>2</sup> et un chef de file du monde des télécommunications, de l'astronautique ([Canadarm](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadarm), [Canadarm-2](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadarm_2), [SPAR Aeorospatiale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spar_Aerospace), [RADARSAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADARSAT), [jalons](http://www.asc-csa.gc.ca/eng/about/milestones.asp)) et de l'aéronautique ([Arrow](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avro_Canada_CF-105_Arrow), [Bombardier](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_A%C3%A9ronautique)), entre autres, dont le génie a parfois été temporisé (voire [saboté](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A220#Probl%C3%A8mes_financiers) et [cannibalisé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accord_Canada%E2%80%93%C3%89tats-Unis%E2%80%93Mexique)) par ses alliances historiques...

---

L'on doit au Belge [J.H. Rosny aîné](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/J.-H._Rosny_a%C3%AEn%C3%A9) la recréation du terme *astronautique* (DHLF) et l'[invention](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronaute#Astronaute)  du terme [*astronaute*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/astronaute) en français (1928). Le terme convient parfaitement en terminologie et on en est reconnaissant. Mais on recherche un mot qui laisse sa marque dans les médias (évidemment on peut avoir l'épithète *canadien* ou le complément du nom *de l'[Agence spatiale canadienne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agence_spatiale_canadienne)* en apport à *astronaute*) et qui soit inspirant et évocateur de la contribution « stellaire », exceptionnelle, du Canada (et des Québécois) à l'exploration de l'espace. On connaît les préfixes [*canado-*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/canado-) et [*québéco-*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Pr%C3%A9fixes_nationaux_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Q) qui donneraient *canadonaute*, *québéconaute*, mais on note qu'avec *taïkonaute* (Chine) et *vyomanaute* (Inde) on s'appuie sur une forme de « translittération » de mots propres aux langues en question. Le français parlé au Canada dispose peut-être des particularités lui permettant de contribuer un préfixe à associer au suffixe [*-naute*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-naute).

---

- Est-on capable d'identifier dans la langue un terme (ou par
  association : [Canada](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada), [Québec](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qu%C3%A9bec)) servant à former un tel
  préfixe, ou de proposer un néologisme que l'on jugerait satisfaisant
  pour ces fins (médias, grand public) et d'expliquer pourquoi il le
  serait ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Par exemple, [David Saint-Jacques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Saint-Jacques) est médecin, astrophysicien et ingénieur physique ; [Chris Hadfield](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Hadfield) est un pilote d'avions de chasse ayant le grade de Colonel ; [Julie Payette](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julie_Payette) est une ingénieure électrique et informatique ; [Marc Garneau](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Garneau) est un ingénieur électrique et était instructeur et capitaine de frégate de la marine canadienne.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Le Canada est le premier pays après les États-Unis et la Russie à avoir conçu et fabriqué un satellite artificiel ([Alouette](http://www.asc-csa.gc.ca/fra/satellites/alouette.asp), aussi [ici](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alouette_1)). Il est entre autres choses le premier à avoir déployé un satellite utilisant la *bande Ku* ([Hermes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_de_technologie_des_t%C3%A9l%C3%A9communications)) ; le premier à avoir mis en orbite un satellite géostationnaire non militaire à usage domestique de portée nationale ([Anik](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anik), [deux ans](https://history.nasa.gov/satcomhistory.html) avant les Américains) ; et un membre fondateur d'[Intelsat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelsat)/[ITSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Telecommunications_Satellite_Organization) incorporant le désir exprimé dans la [Résolution 1721 (XVI)](http://www.unoosa.org/pdf/gares/ARES_16_1721F.pdf) des Nations-Unies sur la *Coopération internationale touchant les utilisations pacifiques de l'espace extra-atmosphérique*.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

D'après moi, le terme "**spationaute**" - *issu des mots grecs kosmos (univers) et nautes (navigateur)* - est le plus logique, universel et correspond effectivement à l'état de l'art (d'un point de vue technique) actuel sur ce sujet.

---

Concernant "*astronaute*" : issu du grec ástron (étoile) et nautes (navigateur), ne corresponds pas à l'état de l'art (nous ne sommes actuellement pas encore capable de transporter des hommes entre deux étoiles... )

Concernant "*spationaute*" est un mot hybride venant du latin spatium (espace) et du grec nautes (navigateur), cela ne parait pas très logique d'hybrider du latin et du grec.

---

L'espace est un sujet "stratégique" et "géopolitique" donc cela peut apparaitre important - du point de vue de la communication/propagande d'un pays - de pouvoir se différencier des autres. 
Mais dans le fond, d'après moi cela reste soit de la "masturbation" intellectuelle, soit un problème d'ego (nationaliste).

---

[source](https://www.anecdote-du-jour.com/spationaute-astronaute-cosmonaute-quelle-difference/)